# What does 国产地效船双船 mean?

Tags: meaning

Apparently it means "domestically produced fixed-wing amphibian aircraft" but I can't find this on any dictionary.  Can you break it down for me?

Comment: As he said below, check it. '双体船‘ would be a catamaran. Sure it's right?

Comment: Can you provide more context and your own analysis?

Comment: They're not `双体船`. Basicly your understanding is right. They're `domestically produced fixed-wing amphibian aircraft`. According to this([国产地效船双船试飞](http://news.ifeng.com/a/20150417/43574217_0.shtml?rdmx=1743185583#p=1)) and this([海南自主研发地效翼船海口首次实现双船试飞](http://tech.ifeng.com/a/20150417/41058736_0.shtml#p=1)), two of them succeeded in test flight.

Answer (score 1):

first, it is not 国产地效船双船+试飞. It should be 国产地效船+双船试飞.

Second, if you want to add 双船 to 国产地效船 as a phrase, you should go with 国产地效双（体）船.

Answer (score 0):

ground effect vehicle(GEV) 地效飞行器
catamaran 双体船

ground effect catamaran